# How to solve the error "Class PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx" not found?

Tags: php

I was trying to import excel files using PhpSpreadsheet.
My file structure is:

```
 public_html/import-excel
```

Inside import-excel are these files/folders:

```
    PhpOffice
    Sql
    Templates
    Uploads
    Datasource.php
    index.php
```

Code starts with this in Datasource.php:

```
    namespace Phppot;
    class DataSource
{
```

Code in index.php:

```
    use Phppot\DataSource;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;

    require_once 'DataSource.php';

    $db = new DataSource();
    $conn = $db->getConnection();

    if (isset($_POST["import"])) {
    and so on
```

When I try to upload files, it shows the error:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx'
> not
> found in
> /home/domaincom/public_html/import-excel/index.php:32 Stack trace: #0 {main}
> thrown in
> /home/domaincom/public_html/import-excel/index.php on line 32"

I don't know what to do next. I'm stuck at here.

Comment: Where/how did you install `PhpOffice`/`PhpSpreadsheet`? composer?

Comment: No, I couldn't use composer as I'm on a shared host. I downloaded PhpSpreadsheet and put it inside the folder 'PhpOffice'.

Comment: There seems to be no folder `PhpOffice` according to your files/folders list

Comment: You need to `require_once` or `include_once` the files you want to `use` first. (Usually, when using `composer` this is done via `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`)

Comment: ok, I will do it.